# How to change the structure of df according date

Tags: python, pandas

My initial pandas df looks as follows:

| ID | Parameter | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 05.05.2023 | 07.05.2023 |
| 2 | 2 | 05.05.2023 | 06.05.2023 |
| 3 | 1 | 08.05.2023 | 09.05.2023 |

Is it possible to get the following structure out of the dataframe? In fact I want to unpivot the time period.

| ID | Parameter | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 05.05.2023 |
| 1 | 4 | 06.05.2023 |
| 1 | 4 | 07.05.2023 |
| 2 | 2 | 05.05.2023 |
| 2 | 2 | 06.05.2023 |
| 3 | 1 | 08.05.2023 |
| 3 | 1 | 09.05.2023 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert both columns to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), create new rows by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with subtraction columns converted to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), last use counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and convert to days timedeltas added to `Start` column by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is remove column after using:

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True)
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.pop('End').sub(df['Start']).dt.days + 1)]
td = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')

df['Date'] = df.pop('Start').add(td).dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
   ID  Parameter        Date
0   1          4  05.05.2023
1   1          4  06.05.2023
2   1          4  07.05.2023
3   2          2  05.05.2023
4   2          2  06.05.2023
5   3          1  08.05.2023
6   3          1  09.05.2023
```